# Getting error "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a code block that leads to a "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" error. When I click the submit button, with NONE of the radio buttons checked, the web page status bar displays "waiting for response from host" and then display the "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage". When I walk through the code in visual studio, the code executes fine, and none of the catch blocks are executed.

[image]

How can I **trap the error and determine why** the error page is being displayed?

```
    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (rbtnSearchBy1.Checked)
            {
                Server.Transfer("ViewEmpHistory.aspx");
            }
            if (rbtnSearchBy2.Checked)
            {
                Server.Transfer("SearchEmp.aspx");
            }
            if (rbtnSearchBy3.Checked)
            {
                Server.Transfer("ViewEmpCard.aspx");
            }
        }

        catch (ThreadAbortException)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: With no checkbox selected, What are you expecting for behavior? Your logic doesn't call Transfer for that case.

Comment: I am expecting it to NOT go to the ""Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" error....

Comment: but you send the request, and then the response serves you no response. Maybe you should consider adding something like else { Server.Transfer("StandardErrorPage.aspx") }

Comment: When you click on "Show Details" on the Internet Explorer error page, what's the error code?  http 500?  Other?

Comment: Based on the code. I will assume the OP will recieve a blank 200 response. And therefore IE will give its standard error page since there is no content to render

Comment: This problem can be caused by a variety of issues, including:
•Internet connectivity has been lost.
•The website is temporarily unavailable.
•The Domain Name Server (DNS) is not reachable.
•The Domain Name Server (DNS) does not have a listing for the website's domain.
•There might be a typing error in the address.
•If this is an HTTPS (secure) address, click Tools, click Internet Options, click Advanced, and check to be sure the SSL and TLS protocols are enabled under the security section.

Comment: @Sean... how can I determine if I am getting a blank 200 response?

Comment: @DotNetRookie You may find it easier to replace your throw and Response.Write with Tracing; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever .cs page your "btnSubmit_Click" is on, put a breakpoint on **that** page_load event.
 Also, put a breakpoint on the page_load event of "ViewEmpHistory.aspx", "SearchEmp.aspx" & "ViewEmpCard.aspx". (so now you have four breakpoints).

Step through  the project again and make sure all parameter values are being passed correctly,  also make sure that you have correct logic (if applicable) for `If (!PostbacK)` conditions etc.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

if you don't select one radiobutton it's normal that you don't enter in your catch , because  your application no throw exception.
but you can view your eventlog

Enter in your cmd : eventvwr to access your event log

[image]

Comment: Event viewer has no related information (when looking at the timestamp)

Answer (score 1):

To debug these kind of issues, I often find it easier to use Tracing.

You can turn on tracing at the [application level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x5wc973.aspx), or at the [page level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94c55d08.aspx).

Your method call will then become:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (rbtnSearchBy1.Checked)
        {
            Server.Transfer("ViewEmpHistory.aspx");
        }
        if (rbtnSearchBy2.Checked)
        {
            Server.Transfer("SearchEmp.aspx");
        }
        if (rbtnSearchBy3.Checked)
        {
            Server.Transfer("ViewEmpCard.aspx");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.Warn("Exception Caught", "Exception: btnSubmit_Click", ex);
    }
}
```

You can look at the trace log by then navigating to the [Trace Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwh16c6c.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

What you've done is not exactly well structured. It's cleaner if the blocks are  exclusive - which is why I've added the else statements to the code below. I've also indicated where you would want to handle the state where no button is checked in comments.

But you're right, there isn't any exception being thrown. Your code didn't throw one, and when you end processing a request without returning any type of response it doesn't cause an exception.

```
        if (rbtnSearchBy1.Checked)
        {
            Server.Transfer("ViewEmpHistory.aspx");
        }
        else if (rbtnSearchBy2.Checked)
        {
            Server.Transfer("SearchEmp.aspx");
        }
        else if (rbtnSearchBy3.Checked)
        {
            Server.Transfer("ViewEmpCard.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
          // Here's where the logic will flow to if no radio button is clicked.
          // We could 
          // * Server.Transfer to a default location
          // * Throw an exception
          // * Do nothing, which returns no response, and causes
          //   IE to complain that it could not display the webpage.
        }
```